# Is my use of pointers in this C program correct?

Tags: c, pointers

For example:

This is what I tried:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <ctype.h>

char *mystrcat(char *s1p, char *s2p); 
char main(void)
{
    ...........................
}

char *mystrcat(char *s1p, char *s2p) 
{

    printf("whatever = %s%s\n", s1p, s2p);
    return 0;   
}
```

How do I make this work with the 3rd pointer and have it store `p1` and `p2`?

Comment: Is there any problem with the code? If you just want the code to be reviewed I suggest http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: @Hawken: NO! Never pass unfiltered input to printf... what if the input was "Hello %s"? Or "Hello %s, I am %s and I am %d years old!"? You've just called printf("Hello %s, I am %s and I am %d years old!")

Comment: @NikB. Sorry, my apologies. Anyway, with compile-time strings it's not an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace: `*mystrcat(string1, string2);`
With: `char *string3 = mystrcat(string1, string2);`

Also if your teacher wants char*'s instead of

```
char string1[80];  
char string2[80];
```

You could do

```
char *string1 = malloc(80*sizeof(char));
char *string2 = malloc(80*sizeof(char));
```

To concat your strings:

```
char *mystrcat(char *s1p,char *s2p) {
    char *cat = malloc(2*80*sizeof(char));
    int i = 0;
    while(s1p[i]!='\o') {
        cat[i] = s1p[i];
        i++;
    }
    int j = 0;
    while(s2p[j]!='\o') {
        cat[i+j] = s2p[j];
        j++;
    }
    return cat;   
}
```

Comment: i made some of the chnages, but i keep getting a error on malloc

Comment: keeps saying malloc is undefined, would i have to write it at the top, Define malloc 80, something like that

Comment: that didnt work, im still keep getting an error on malloc, error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'char *'

Comment: @AmandeepSinghDhari You must cast it to a `char *` replace the line with malloc with this: `char *cat = (char *) malloc(2 * 80 * sizeof(char));`. Also, your main should have a return-type of `int`, not `char`.

Answer (score 0):

Bad coding habits aside (I've been doing C for a while, still haven't fixed some of em), there is one error I see: *mystrcat(string1, string2). The return type is char*, but the function itself has the pointer "in it" (hard to explain). So it should just be mystrcat(string1, string2)

Comment: my lectuer gave me this, and i have to use that

Comment: and what Bad coding habits  do i have, so i can leran from them

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to write a function to concatenate strings. To do this you need to be able to visualize the strings in your head, the 2 input strings and the resultant string.

Here's an algorithm that should solve it:

- Create a result string that has enough space for the total number of characters in the  given input plus 1 for the terminating nul char.
- Copy the bytes from the first string to the result.
- Append the characters from the esconds string to the result
- Append a nul character
- return the result

Programming is the ability to see a problem, devise an algorithm and then implement in a programming language.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *mystrcat(char*s1p, char*s2p); // Prototype

int main(void)
{

    char *string1 = malloc(80*sizeof(char));
    char *string2 = malloc(80*sizeof(char));

    printf("Enter in string 1");
    scanf("%s", string1);

    printf("Enter in string 2");
    scanf("%s", string2);

    char *mystrcat((string1,string2));
return 0;

}

char *mystrcat(char *s1p,char *s2p) 
{

    char *cat = malloc(2*80*sizeof(char));
int i = 0;
while(s1p[i]!='\o') {
    cat[i] = s1p[i];
    i++;
}
int j = 0;
while(s2p[j]!='\o') {
    cat[i+j] = s2p[j];
    j++;
}
return cat;


}
```

this is the code i got so far with all of your lots help, i included everthing top to bottom, i am using MSVS 2012 and the reason i am posting this because i have an error on 'malloc' the error as fellows

```
3   IntelliSense: a value of type "void *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "char *"  c:\Users\Sid\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\PORTFOLIO QUESTION 3\PORTFOLIO QUESTION 3\PORTFOLIO QUESTION 3.cpp   32
```